# Where is the Subversion executable located

Tags: svn

I've installed Subversion via the command line.  But I need to find the executable to point to it in my IDE.  Do you know where it is located in the Ubuntu file system?

Comment: Did you try `whereis svn` ?

Comment: Executables are usually in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I was attempting to use the find command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `which` will tell you where a command is found in your current environment - it may be a better choice than `whereis`, since it searches the path of your current shell, rather than a fixed set of paths.

Usage is:

```
$ which svn
/usr/bin/svn
```

Comment: it says it's in usr/bin/svn and in dolphin file managers it's there but intellji rider refuses to load or even list it in it's file explorer.

Answer (score 3):

A quick `whereis svn` gives me the following paths:

```
nits@excalibur:~$ whereis svn
svn: /usr/bin/svn /usr/bin/X11/svn /usr/share/man/man1/svn.1.gz
```

So, there you have it, it's at `/usr/bin/svn`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to get the binary location from the Subversion package:

```
dpkg -L subversion | grep bin | grep '\<svn$'
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/svn
```